# How to scroll 2 GridViews in a Linear Layout together?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, scroll

I have two gridviews in a linear layout. Here is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <GridView
    android:id="@+id/leftGrid2"
    android:layout_width="416dp"
    android:layout_height="1078dp"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >

  </GridView>

   <GridView
    android:id="@+id/rightGrid2"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >

    </GridView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

How to make these two grid views scroll together or synchronize them ? They have two seperate scrolls when i run my application.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show us screen shots of what you are talking about?

Comment: @prolink007 both my grid views scroll separately..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridView is provided the [smoothScrollToPosition(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) method via its AbsLisView parent. This will scroll to the position you desire. Now, you listen for ScrollEvent with the [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html). Now just tie these together:

```
GridView other;
@Override public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstItem, int visItems, int total) {
    other.smoothScrollToPosition(firstItem);
}
```

Now, this will **not!** work as expected if your two views are not comparable ie. same content quantity.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this once before with a Gallery. You should be able to take this and apply it to `GridView` pretty easily:

```
public class DualGallery extends Gallery {

/**
 * Second {@link Gallery}
 */
public DualGallery b;

/**
 * Current {@link Context}
 */
Context mContext;

/**
 * Constructor that takes the {@link Context} and second {@link DualGallery}
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param b
 */
public DualGallery(Context context, DualGallery b) {
    super(context);

    this.mContext = context;

    this.b = b;

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    // Scrolls this and the second Gallery avoiding an endless loop
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY)
            && b.onFling2(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    // Scrolls this and the second Gallery avoiding an endless loop
    return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY)
            && b.onScroll2(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
}

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    super.setOnClickListener(l);
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * Special function to redirect to just
 * {@link Gallery#onFling(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)}
 * 
 * @param e1
 * @param e2
 * @param velocityX
 * @param velocityY
 * @return
 */
public boolean onFling2(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}

/**
 * Special function to redirect to just
 * {@link Gallery#onScroll(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)}
 * 
 * @param e1
 * @param e2
 * @param distanceX
 * @param distanceY
 * @return
 */
public boolean onScroll2(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
}
```

}